# TeamCity 9 data path

Tags: teamcity, build-process, teamcity-9.0

I have been using TeamCity 9.0.5 for a while now. But today when i started up the server i was greeted with the "TeamCity First Start" which i had last seen some months ago. I also see the version at the bottom has changed from 9.0.5 to 9.1.4.

I did not run any updates so i am wondering what happened. Also, it expects to find the data directory at "/root/.BuildServer" now and the "/root/" does not exist. I have all projects and TC data stored at "home//.BuildServer" but it's not picking that up.

So, the question why did it really upgrade on it's own? Also, how do i setup the data directory path? I have looked at official link like [this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/TeamCity+Data+Directory) but everything seems fine according to that. I have the `teamcity-startup.properties` file which points to correct path.

I have added the screenshot for further clarification.

[image]

Comment: Could you please double check that you started TeamCity installed in the <TeamCity home directory> and that <TeamCity home directory>/conf/teamcity-startup.properties file is also located in the same directory? Is the TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH variable set?
Also please post the teamcity-server.log file covering the server startup.

Comment: @AlinaMishina Apparently, it was happening because i was running TeamCity using `sudo`. When i did it without `sudo`, it started up just fine.

Comment: I wonder what might prevent access to certain features when in super user mode.